# How to remove header and footer from Webpage of DotnetNuke?

Tags: c#, css, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I am begginer of DotnetNuke. I am facing crutial problem now a days. In WordPress, we are providing functionality to manage FullWidth and StandAlone design.

FullWidth: Content of our module should fit in content windows. It will keep header and footer of Website page.

StandAlone: Content of our module should not show header and footer of the website. It just show Module. It should use full screen.

Can anybody suggest me how can I remove header and footer incase user have set StandAlone?

Answer (score 0):

All of these items are managed by your site's theme, formerly called a skin.

So, you can create a theme, modify an existing theme, or get a skin that someone else has created.

The options are uncountable.